# Profile C# class creation

Tags: c#

I have a class like this with some code to profile how long the constructor takes to execute. I would ideally like to have this code injected automatically, preferably in the BaseClass. Is this possible somehow so I don't need to add it to every class?

```
public MyClass : BaseClass
{
    public MyClass() : base()
    {
        using (new ProfileRegion("MyClass"))
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't add instrumentation code yourself - use a profiler to do this for you.  There are many wonderful .NET profilers out there to choose from (I have had many good experiences using [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) but there are other choices as well).

Comment: Seconded; I've been using ANTS this week - very impressed.

Comment: I am a big fan of ANTS but today I tried out the new performance testing in VS 2010 (Beta 2) and I must admit it was pretty slick as well.  I would definitely recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling is generally cross cutting concern. Look for Dependency Injection Patterns. [Martin Fowler's](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) article is a good start. Then look for .NET IoC implementations like [Unity](http://codeplex.com/unity) or [Spring Framework](http://springframework.net). You will need to have [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) in place through which all the consumers of your class(es) get the instance and in that Factory you inject the profiling [aspect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Spring Framework Sample Code

```
IInvoicingWorkflowProider p = (IInvoicingWorkflowProider)Factory.createInvoicingWorkflowProvider();

ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory(p);  //This is Spring's
pf.AddAdvice(new TracingAspect());      //TracingAspect is my aspect implementation

return (IInvoicingWorkflowProider)pf.GetProxy();
```